# java script navigation using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, navigation

I am new to javascript programming so feel free to correct me .
In the code below **why do i have to write nextSibling twice instead of just once** , cause i checked the definition and it said :*returns the next child node of an element at the same level as the current child node.*

**And then again referencing h1 i have to write firstChild & again nextSibling**(*Why is nextSibling present in this line*)I am confused here , please explain or if possible give me a good link to a website that explains my confusion below. Thank You

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 8, Example 4</title>
</head>
    <body>
      <h1 id="heading1">SOME HEADING</h1>
      <p id="para1">Welcome to my Humble website.</p>

      <script>
      var html_element = document.documentElement;
      alert(html_element.tagName); //HTML

      var head_element = html_element.firstChild;
      alert(head_element.tagName); //HEAD

      var body_element = head_element.nextSibling.nextSibling;
      alert(body_element.tagName); // BODY

      var h1_element = body_element.firstChild.nextSibling;
      alert(h1_element.tagName); //H1

      var p_element = h1_element.nextSibling.nextSibling;
      alert(p_element.tagName); //P


      </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you use jQuery ? It's really useful for simplifying dom queries.

Comment: use `nextElementSibling` to skip the "empty" text nodes (that exist between tags) ... also use `firstElementChild` for the same reasons

Comment: p.s. `body = document.body` ... `head = document.head` (note: document.head does not exist in IE8 or earlier)

Comment: `document.body` isn't this one better? Although _jX_ already answered at first comment.

Comment: as a brief explanation ... between `<body>` and `<h1>` you have a line break, and some spaces ... therefore the first child node of `<body>` is a text node ... however, the first ELEMENT child is `<h1>`